# Programs open IE, despite Chrome being default browser

Tags: windows-7, browser

I have Google Chrome set as the default browser on my computer, but some programs are still opening Internet Explorer windows. Why is this, and is there anything I can do to fix it? I am using Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m, although I believe this is a Windows problem, not a Chrome problem.

Edit: I can disable IE through Windows, but when I do, the program which launches it throws a "Class not registered" script error. The following code is the script which launches it:

```
<!-- Script to enable drop down suggestions and link source file-->
<script>

//Funtion to open new window when any item is selected from suggested drop down
function callback(item) {
    window.open(item.extra);
}

jQuery(function() {
    $.getJSON("*url snipped*",
        function(data) {
            $('input#suggestBox2').jsonSuggest(data, {maxResults:20,onSelect:callback});
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

What part of that causes it to open in IE, and is there any way to redirect it?

Comment: Please _always_ include the operating system and versions of the software you are having problems with.

Comment: @terdon - Sorry, forgot that that might be important :)

Comment: Thanks, what is really important is the Operating System since this type of problem often depends on the OS version (plus, not everyone uses windows, certainly not everyone here :) )

Comment: Also, the version of Windows might be relevant ;)

Comment: @terdon - I know that well, I used Fedora for a while. It just slipped my mind for a moment.

Comment: @Everett - Look at the tags ;)

Comment: The program in question uses plain JavaScript? How exactly does the program run? Is it a web app?

Comment: @Karan - I suspect it is, although it's launched as a regular application and runs in its own window.

Comment: So if it's an EXE, where did you get the JS source from?

Comment: @Karan - Right clicked and hit view source. Based on Oliver S's answer, it seems like it uses the IE rendering engine in the exe or something. Not sure how that sort of thing works.

Comment: Then it sounds like it's just a thin wrapper around the IE Web Browser control. Can't redirect a hard coded app call in that case, unless... Can you try my answer below?

Comment: @SaintWacko What? me reads good... Sorry missed the obvious there.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK some software using hardcoded option of which browser to open for page, and you cant change it even though you have setup some other browser then IE as default. Mostly these are some launchers go different games and some corporative software.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm having issues with: corporate software. Hopefully someone has a way to change it, though; a workaround of some sort.

Comment: I think if you completely delete IE from system via components management(might be wrong name), and then OS will lauch your default browser due to unavailable IE

Comment: I suspected I would have to do that.

Comment: Mostly this "issue" because corporative software can be very specific and require something unusual, so developing page for only IE, would cost much less then develop page for all browsers.

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but if I copy the URL into Chrome, it works exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, usually all browsers can play same things as IE. I'm not sure what were reasons for doing that, either lazy developers or some difficulties with developing

Comment: @SaintWacko - If the program is hardcoded to launch IE then there is nothing to fix except the software that i shardcoded to launch IE.

Comment: @Ramhound - I was hoping to find some way to intercept the script request and send it to Chrome instead of IE.

Answer (score 1):

Where is that code executed from?

If it's already running inside a browser, then `window.open` should open another window in the same browser.

There is no indication that that code should invoke anything but the standard browser or the host browser it is running in.

Comment: Hm... If it's a standalone application that uses the IE rendering engine (that may not be exactly how it works, but something like that), would it open an IE window?

Comment: @SaintWacko looks like it is a program which has a built in browser window and these kind of things use the windows default browser like the one that you create using an AutoRun making program. Can you tell me which programs give this error? have you build them?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use Internet Explorer for anything, you can disable Internet Explorer so that your programs do open up google chrome because that will be your only browser.

Windows7:

1. Click the start button
2. Type "Windows Features"
3. Click on "Turn Windows features on or off"
4. Scroll through the list and find the Internet Explorer box and uncheck it
5. Restart your computer

Then it should be gone

For others, click [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957700)

Comment: Well, that disabled it, but now the program throws a "Class not registered" script exception where it would normally open IE.

Comment: I've added the bit of script that does it at the bottom of my question, as it didn't format properly in a comment.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I've never had the problem, I apologize that I couldn't help anymore.

Comment: They must have done something different to force it to launch in IE.

Comment: Saw this.

function PopIma(img) {
w=open(img,'hej','top=0,left=0,width=10,'+
'height=10,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,'+
'resizable=yes');
}

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?58228.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6617/discussion-between-justind-and-saintwacko)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've disabled IE via the Windows Features dialog, try the following. No guarantees it will work or that it won't break anything else; it's just something that suddenly occurred to me. As always, be *careful* while editing the Registry!

Open **Regedit** and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

Under that key, change the value of **(Default)** *from*:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

*to*:

```
Drive:\Full\path\to\Chrome.exe
```

Similarly, change the value of **Path** *from*:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
```

*to*:

```
Drive:\Full\path\to
```

i.e. the path to the directory where Chrome.exe resides.

Also navigate to the following key and **make the *same* two changes**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\IEXPLORE.EXE
```

Now confirm that the changes have worked by typing "iexplore" in the **Run** dialog. If Chrome starts up, all's fine. Now run the program, cross your fingers and see if it launches Chrome instead of IE. If it does, let me know and we'll celebrate! :)

Answer (score -1):

programs pinned to IE will always open with IE

to unpin from IE..
display site in question
hold down shift key
drag to desktop
release shift key

now Chrome, etc will work for that site